# How to fix "This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'UIImageView' does not adopt it."

Tags: swift, uiimageview, nsdate, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I am trying to archive my `UIImageView` which contains many `CaLayers` and `Views`.

I am successfully saved 'UIImageView' as Data through below code..

```
        let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.backgroundIV!, requiringSecureCoding: false)
        print(data)
```

When I try to un-archived `UIImageView` form `Data` via below code.

```
do {
            let imageView: UIImageView = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIImageView.self, from: data!)!
            self.backgroundIV = imageView
            print("Un Archived...")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
   }
```

I got this error..

```
Optional(922 bytes)
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'UIImageView' does not adopt it." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'UIImageView' does not adopt it.
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to archive an imageView? Just save your image

Comment: I am parsing SVG paths and convert them into CAShapeLayers, after that I add that layers into UIImageView as sublayers. I can change layers color as well as resize them, I need to saved them into Local storage for future edit.
I tried to saved image of UIImageView as data then retrieve it but I can't perform any actions on it because image does not contain layers anymore after saved to data.
That's why I am trying to saved my whole UIImageView as Data.

Comment: Save all info and reconstruct your image view. Btw you should be using a container view not an image view

Comment: I don't how to save all info because I am new in iOS.